# Data Query for Health.SE

Tags: discussion, scope, data-explorer

Health is a relatively small site currently in beta. We fear that new users might misunderstand what we are there for, but do not have the numbers to back it up. As we are a small site, we currently have no one with knowledge of the SE data queries.

We are looking for numbers of how many first posts were deleted or closed in the last month, and how many first answers were deleted or have a rating of -2.

Could I ask a question on SO for how to write  a query for us? Or  this not suitable on SO or SO Meta?

Comment: Asking others to do the work sounds off-topic to me. [Maybe you have to give it a try by yourself first](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial). Then, if your query doesn't work, you have a good basis for a question (at least on MSE, I think).

Comment: @honk Thanks for the link. Don't know why I didn't find that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it would not be a good question to just describe a query that you want and ask someone to write the query for you.  SO isn't a free coding service for people that want code written for them but don't know how to write code.